# Replacing a string in to an association list Scheme

Tags: string, list, scheme, racket

update-or-add is an association list, contains an integer k and a string str. If there is a number that is the same as k in the association list, then it replaces the associated string with str.

For example,
    (update-or-add empty 2 "new")=> (list 2 "new")

```
(update-or-add
     (list (list 3 "three") (list 1 "one") (list 2 "two")) 3 "new3")
    => (list (list 3 "new3") (list 1 "one") (list 2 "two"))

(update-or-add
     (list (list 3 "three") (list 1 "one") (list 2 "two")) 0 "z")
    => (list (list 3 "three") (list 1 "one") (list 2 "two") (list 0 "z"))
```

Note that the produced list must be an association list with the keys in the **same relative order** as alst (if updating the value associated with existing key k, as in the first example), and if adding a new key and value, this new association should be added at the end of alst (as in the third example).

And here is my code right now:

```
(define (update-or-add alst k v)
  (cond
    [(empty? alst) (list k v)]
    [(equal? (first (first alst)) k) 
     (cons (list (first(first alst)) v) 
           (add-or-update (rest alst) k v))] 
    [else (cons (first alst) (update-or-add (rest alst) k v))]))
```

But the second and the third tests stated above didn't pass, can anyone show me where the problem is and how to correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a recursive function your base case needs to match the general pattern.
Meaning

```
  (update-or-add empty 2 "new")  =>  '((2 "new"))
```

This should do it

```
(define (add-or-update alst k v) 
  (cond [(empty? alst) (list(list k v))] 
        [(equal? (first (first alst)) k) (cons (list k v) (rest alst))] 
        [else (cons (first alst) (add-or-update (rest alst) k v))]))
```